# Find the IP address of my machine by reading a file

Tags: linux, ip-address

This is part of school project I'm working on where I can only read files from a linux machine (I can't execute commands or anything else) and I need to find its public IP. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is `/proc` considered a file in these requirements? Then you could try `/proc/net/fib_trie`.

Comment: You're not sure if you need the IP  ? What do you mean by "I can only read files" because more or less everything is a file in linux (a file descriptor more exactly) . What have you tried ?

Comment: @dejdej It's not easy to describe why I can only read files, but what I am asking is if there is the IP addres of a linux machine written somewhere in a file by the system. I have tried searching stack overflow and google for such a file but I have not found it yet (the answer above yours provided me with something useful)

Comment: @KarstenKoop Yes, thank you, it is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Below command will give you the public ip of that machine.

`wget -qO - icanhazip.com`

if you are using Ubuntu Linux and you don't have wget command then run below code.

`sudo apt-get install wget`

Comment: The point of the question is that I don't want a command to do that. I want to find the public IP of a linux machine by reading an appropriate file.